# Maven with Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-juno

I just upgraded to Eclipse v4.2 (Juno). The Maven plugin seems to be missing. How do I get it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

All the info you need, is provided in the [release announcement for m2e 1.1](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg02654.html):

> m2e 1.1 has been released as part of Eclipse Juno simultaneous release today.
>
> [...]
>
> m2e 1.1 is already included in "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" package available from http://eclipse.org/downloads/ or it can be installed from Eclipse Juno release repository [2]. Eclipse 3.7/Indigo users can install the new version from m2e release repository [3]
>
> [...]
>
> [2] http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
>
> [3] http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Answer (score 35):

m2e is only included in the Java developer version of Eclipse, as you can see on this page ("Maven" topic): http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

However, an easy way to get m2e is through the Eclipse Marketplace:

Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace and look for m2e. Click "Maven Integration for Eclipse", then on Install (or drag and drop the install link to your running Eclipse workspace if you opened the marketplace in a browser), et voila!

Direct browser access: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse

Comment: Does this apply for the Java EE Developers edition? I cannot see it within the installed software; but i think i didnt saw it either with indigo on installed software tab but it was there (considering by the popup menus content)

Comment: I have no idea, but it would be worth to test it and maybe to indicate the Eclipse Foundation their page is wrong.

Comment: This is weird, I don't even see the Eclipse Marketplace under OS X with the latest Juno release

Comment: I tried to install it from the market place and it got installed but when I click on a project , it doesn't show the Enable Maven dependency option. It does show maven option in preferences section. Wat could be wrong?

Comment: @Metalhead: Right click on your project. If a Maven item appears, try to select "Add Maven nature".

Comment: The Java EE edition does not have m2e included.  I usually just install m2e-wtp from Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Looking at the "compare" page I indicated in my answer, it seems M2E is now part of the Java EE edition. So I don't know for Kepler, but it seems to be included in the Luna version.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to install m2e (maven project for eclipse) using the Help -> Install New Software dialog. On that dialog open the Juno site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno) and expand the Collaboration group (or type m2e into the filter). Select the two m2e options and follow the installation dialog

Answer (score 6):

From Eclipse

- Go to Help
- Eclipse Marketplace
- Search for m2e or maven integration for eclipse
- click on Install against - 'Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer) 1.4'
- Restart and Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was getting when tried to install m2e from Eclipse Market place.
I am using Eclipse Juno.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.5.0.20140606-0033]

However, the below links is perfect, it works for me.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-wtp-juno-0

Regards,
Bilal