# Maven dependecny is not available in eclipse java build path

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-juno, buildpath

I checked out an existing `eclipse` project from `SVN`. Then I converted it to `Maven` project.
The project is compile with Maven target `clean install` perfectly no problem. But the eclipse doesn't identify any dependency jar file. Basically it does not know the `Maven` `repo` path. It knows only JDK path. So all my java classes are with full of red lines.

Everything in this site and google I checked all fine. But why eclipse can not find the mvn repo? 
eclipse version     = `JUNO Version: 4.2.2.`   ( I think this has inbuilt maven plugin)
Maven plugin detail = M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse  version - 1.4.0, Provider - Eclipse.org -m2e

[image]

UPDATE ======================

If I checkout the source code separately and import it as a maven project that way its working. But I want to know why if I checkout the code through Subclipse and convert it to maven project is not working?

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
# use maven to control your eclipse .project and .classpath files, that is
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and then restart your eclipse (or switch your workspace and then back).

Make sure you have the m2e plugin, - from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11242107/2970947), you should read the [Release Notes](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg02654.html) and add this to your update sites - "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" and "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases".

Comment: From which location I should trigger these commands? Goto Workspace>project location or..

Comment: From wherever the mvn clean install works - e.g. where your pom.xml is.

Comment: Still same. both command success but when I open eclipse still I do not see repo in build path window also code is giving errors.

Comment: @user2771655 Added info about m2e plugin to my answer. That really is all you need to do.

Comment: Ok, Why it works when I import the project as a maven project?

Comment: There are two ways I tried. Checkout the project to workspace and import it as a maven project.This way is working fine. But if I use Subclipse plugin and checkout the code through eclipse then convert the project to maven project is the way that gives errors.

Comment: In the words of Groucho Marks, don't do that then.

Comment: I think the problem is with the maven plugin version that ship with JUNO version. I used the in-built maven plugin.

Comment: I was about to post a question about pulling my hair... this answer saved me from doing so. Thank you! +1.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you can actually create an external tool  Run> External Tools> External Tools Configurations. After this you can select your project that you want to setup and run this external tool.

[image: eclipse_eclipse]

or if you have maven plugin installed in eclipse, select your project right click Run As > Maven Build... (see below image). In Goals put "eclipse:eclipse" and click Run

[image]

Comment: can you please post the error trail that you are getting.. Its fairly straight forward to setup eclipse project using this.

Comment: Basically the problem is Java build path does not know the Dependent jars(maven local repo). So my code has errors. But I can build it without any problem. If you see my screen grab you can understand.

Comment: then please have a look at the .classpath file that got generated after running this plugin.