# Missing artifacts on Maven Central Repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

Maven central repository does not have jars and artifacts of Eclipse Juno 4.2 release.
Where can i find all these jars and artifacts(along with pom.xml-including transitive dependencies).It will be helpful for us to resolve all maven dependencies as we are planning to migrate eclipse plugins from 3.2 to 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting a new question, take a look to the old ones.

I think this thread will reply to your : [Maven with Eclipse Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242107/maven-with-eclipse-juno)

Comment: Sorry this was not the thing that I was looking for. Maven Central repository is having all eclipse plugin jars as well as artifacts.Here is the link http://search.maven.org/#browse.But under this we could not find Eclipse Juno 4.2 jars,artifacts and related POM .xml

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar Problem. Perhaps you should consider using Tycho to build Eclipse Plugins with Maven. It supports using eclipse update sites as dependency source. This way you do not need to resolve eclipse dependencies from a Maven repository.

Tycho takes the Manifest file as dependency definition. However it is still possible to include maven dependencies. The concrete plugin project has to have the packaging

```
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
```

If your target platform definition does not contain the needed update sites that contain your dependencies add this to your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>indigo</id>
        <!-- Or juno update site in your case -->
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Additionally you have to configure the build as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <artifact>
                        <!-- coordinates of your target platform definition -->
                    </artifact>
                </target>
                <!-- This allows you to additionally consider pom dependencies -->
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately I could not find artifacts even on Eclipse nexus repository. https://repo.eclipse.org/index.html

Comment: We faced a similar Problem. Perhaps you should consider using Tycho to build Eclipse Plugins with Maven. It supports using eclipse update sites as dependency source. This way you do not need to resolve eclipse dependencies from a Maven repository.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tried creating pom.xml using Tycho commands for Juno artifacts, but POM does not contain all the transitive dependencies.Is there any way to add transitive dependencies also to POM.xmls?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.We have found the transitive dependencies and added seperately in our pom.xml